# How to fix SSD Secure erase disabled for Kingston

Tags: windows-10, ssd, secure-erase

I noticed that my SSD read/write speed dropped. I googled it most results said that a secure erase could help.

I am using Kingston SSD Manager, and it says

> Secure Erase is disabled for this primary drive. Only secondary non-partitioned drives maybe secure erased.

Here is a screenshot 
[image]

Comment: You can't since the drive is the primary partition, in other words, the system drive.  A secure erase is unlikely to resolve anything based on the health status of that drive (i.e. there is nothing wrong with it).

Comment: that makes sense. any ideas on how to improve the performance of the SSD? p.s. feel free to move this to an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: idk that device or software, but look for the TRIM commands. Periodically [ie once a year not once a week;) you could do a full-disk TRIM, which will which will, in non-technical terms, hoover the dust bunnies from under its bed, shakedown its pillows, hand it a coffee & have it bright & fresh for another day. [Process can take a good few hours during which you won't be able to use the computer].

Comment: I see there's only 17.69% free space on the drive. Have you tried increasing the free space on the drive? More space gives the SSD controller more resources, so it can run faster. Perhaps you could move some data to a different physical disk.

Answer (score 1):

Kingston SSD Manager will not allow a drive to be secure erased if it contains any partitions. If your drive contains partitions the Secure Erase button will be inactive and you will see this message.

In the case your drive contains partitions you must remove them using the Disk Management system utility but Please make sure to have a full backup of any important data before you proceed!

1. Right-click the Start Menu button and select Disk Management from the menu.
2. Locate the drive using the physical disk number assigned by Windows (e.g. Disk 1)
3. Right-click on each partition on your disk and select Delete Volume until all partitions have been removed.
4. Click the refresh button in Kingston SSD Manager to rescan your drives and try the Secure Erase Procedure again